# Where to use mouseDown , mouseUp and mouseMove in selenium webdriver?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

Where to use mouseDown , mouseUp and mouseMove in selenium webdriver? and what is the use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're referring to the methods of the Mouse interface, they're not used directly rather through an Actions class. The use is upon you, hovering over the element, checking the title etc. Consider the following code to hover over the element elem

```
WebElement elem = driver.findElement(By.tagName("div"));
Actions action = new Actions(driver);
action.moveToElement(elem);
action.perform();
```

Action holds a reference to a Mouse, and uses the mouseMove method to navigate to an element. If you want a more direct approach to an implementation of the interface you can do

```
 ((HasInputDevices) driver).getMouse()
```

`getMouse()` and `getKeyboard()` are implemented by every driver

Comment: Hello, it is not clear where and how you obtained `action` object. Can you please update your answer with that part of code?

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to the below mentioned url for various mouse and keys event.Description is also provided with the event name.

http://seleniumeasy.com/selenium-tutorials/handling-keyboard-events-and-mouse-hover-events-using-webdriver